# Calculate logout time in using eloquent relations

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an attendance app and I have attendances table which has the following columns:

1. employee_id.
2. attendace_time "datetime".
3. attendace_type "string login/logout".

the company has two work shifts first one from 6 am to 3 pm and the second one from 3 pm to 12 am.

the problem is in the second shift that I can't calculate the logout time and late time because employee can do fingerprint in the 12 am which is the next day and the way that I calculate it like this

```
public function todayLogout()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Attendance::class)
        ->where('attendance_type', 'logout')
        ->whereDate('attendance_time', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
        ->orderBy('attendance_time', 'desc');
}
```

now the above function will not return logout record for employees whom did fingerprint after 12 am because of wheredate condition.

is there anyway to make it work even if I had to change my table structure.

Answer (score 0):

If it is feasible to you, you can shift the day that takes time from 00:00 into 01:00 by increasing time by one hour and take all the values between 24 hour of your time, (also instead of increasing by 1 hour you can increase by minutes or second by using `addMinute()` or `addSecond()` or even more than just one second or minute using `addMinutes(31)` or `addSeconds(31)`)

```
public function todayLogout()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Attendance::class)
        ->where('attendance_type', 'logout')
        ->whereTime('attendance_time', '>', Carbon::today()->addHour())
        ->whereTime('attendance_time', '<' Carbon::today()->addDay()->addHour())
        ->orderBy('attendance_time', 'desc');
}
```